# How to trim specific words when getting content from Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, trim

I have this in my Wordpress template:

```
$my_content = get_the_content();
$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $my_content, 12, '...' );
echo $trimmed_content;
```

This trims the content I am fetching, but **I want to get rid of some words I don't want to show explicitly**. So let's say I don't want to show the word *"coming"* or *"world"* or *"weather"* in the content.

How can I achieve that?

And I have one rather odd request regarding this. I have some words which I use as tags. So let's say something like this: **(tag:** hereComesArandomWord)

What I want to do, is to get rid of **(tag: )** (so also the last parenthese). Is this possible as well?

Comment: Please specify more. Each **coming** word you don't want to any specific place of **coming** word ??

Comment: What do you mean? No, I just want to get rid of some words. Very specifically. I'll provide more examples in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace()` will operate a search and replace on a string.

The previous answer was more or less on the money. You'd simply execute `str_replace()` *before* using `wp_trim_words()`.

Example:

```
$my_content = get_the_content();
$filtered_content = str_replace( array( 'coming', 'world', 'weather' ), '', $my_content );
$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $filtered_content, 12, '...' );
echo $trimmed_content;
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Do you have a proper answer to the other one as well, btw? I mean, removing this: (tag: ) ?

Comment: The same approach would apply assuming it's part of your main content (put tag: in the array). If it's handled separately then your question doesn't contain enough information to provide an answer. Purely as a guess though take a look at `the_tags()` in the WordPress docs. The first parameter lets you set (or remove) the before text

Comment: I understand, yet this is a custom HTML tag. I can do this: "(tag:" but I can't do this "(tag:)", so the last parenthese is always being neglected as there is a word within the tag. I don't know how to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

use `str_replace` to hide (remove) string.

As an example:

```
$trimmed_content = str_replace(array("coming", "world", "weather"), "", $trimmed_content);
echo $trimmed_content;
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not acknowledging my own parameters and settings. I want to trim it and show the first 12 words... plus "..." as you can see in the end. Can you add that too?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum...

**trim specific words**

```
<p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 70, false); ?></p>
```